# jQuery Loader on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I can get the loader too work with the code now - but it does not replace in and call the URL. So the ajax url call should be called within searchable:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">LOAD</button><br /><br />
<div class="spinner bar hide">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="searchtable"><?php include 'hotels/hotelList.php';?></div>
<script>
function myFunction() { 
$('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
$('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

$.ajax({
url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>&arrival=<?php echo $arrival;?>&departure=<?php echo $departure;?>&guests=<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>'
})

.done(function() {
$('.spinner').addClass('hide');
$('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');
});

}
 </script>
```

Comment: All CSS , HTML are working as I get the spinner to show all time.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using $.ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a few recommendations:

- Don't use ids, use classes.
- Don't use `.hide` & `.show` Paul Irish has a nice explanation [here.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/88#issuecomment-72400007)
- Since jq 1.7 you should really not be using `.bind()`.
- I would recommend using `.ajax()` in lieu of `.load()` [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So then your function would look something like

```
function myFunction() {

  $('.search-table').addClass('hide');
  $('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/endpoint'
  })
  .done(function() {
    $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
    $('.search-table').removeClass('hide');
  });

}
```

Working jsbin example [here.](http://jsbin.com/moxazukawi/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: doesen't work. The code is now `<script>
function myFunction() { 
  $('.search-table').addClass('hide');
  $('.spinner bar').removeClass('hide');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php?name=<?php echo $name?>&arrival=<?php echo $arrival?>&departure=<?php echo $departure?>&guests=<?php echo $numberOfGuests?>'
  })
  .done(function() {
    $('.spinner bar').addClass('hide');
    $('.search-table').removeClass('hide');
  });

}
</script>`

Comment: changed code to be according to css class's `<script>
function myFunction() { 
  $('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
  $('.spinner bar').removeClass('hide');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php?name=<?php echo $name?>&arrival=<?php echo $arrival?>&departure=<?php echo $departure?>&guests=<?php echo $numberOfGuests?>'
  })
  .done(function() {
    $('.spinner bar').addClass('hide');
    $('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');
  });

}
</script>`

Comment: What specifically isn't working? The JS is pretty straight forward. What's up with that path? Why does it have a bunch of php vars and echo statements? Is that what it looks like before you render the static asset or are you trying to use that specific path/endpoint? If it's the latter case I can tell you it won't work. Install postman in your browser if you're using chrome and make sure that endpoint is doing what you think it is.

Comment: Right now I got the loader to work - but it don't call the url.

Comment: check the code in top. Loader works but URL is not called and replaced with the css class.

Comment: Yeah, dude I've at this point I've answered your original question, but you didn't answer mine about your URL. Which is entirely a separate issue. I pasted in a working JS bin example.